# HTML5 Boilerplate - Modifying the build.xml for WordPress

Tags: regex, wordpress, optimization, html, boilerplate

I'm trying to get the Build Script that's included in HTML5 BoilerPlate (http://html5boilerplate.com/) to play nicely with WordPress. I've successfully changed the default config to compress style.css in the root of a WordPress theme, but I'm not sure how to modify the build.xml to run through the WordPress header.php and footer.php.

Normally build.xml runs through the index.html file and strips out commenting then, most importantly, changes the version name of the css and js file references.
I'm imagining this should be pretty easy for a developer to figure out, the build.xml uses regular expressions to replace lines of code.

I'd like the build.xml to wizz through my header.php and footer.php, performing the same optimisations as it does with index.html.

Can anyone suggest which parts of the build.xml I need to modify to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you do not need to edit the build.xml file.  Just add the files you want parsed to build/config/default.properties :

```
#
# HTML, PHP, etc files to clean and update script/css references
#
file.pages.default.include  = index.html, 404.html, header.php, footer.php
```