# How do I use HTML5 Boilerplat build script with WordPress theme

Tags: build-automation, html5boilerplate

I'm using HTML5 boilerplate for my first project, which is a WordPress theme, & want to use the build script to compress all my files.

I found this post regarding how to get the script to parse files...

[HTML5 Boilerplate - Modifying the build.xml for WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397197/html5-boilerplate-modifying-the-build-xml-for-wordpress)

... so have added header & footer to my default.properties files, & they're being parse, however my footer file scripts, which I wrapped in `<!-- //-beg- concat_js -->...<!-- //-end- concat_js -->` as detailed in the readme, however all I see in the output file is...

```
<script src="js/${scripts.sha}.js"></script>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  Here's the original section of the footer.php file...

```
<!-- //-beg- concat_js -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

<script>
    var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-XXXXX-X'],['_trackPageview']];
    (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
    g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
</script>
<!-- //-end- concat_js -->
```

Answer (score 0):

After writing this post, I found the `file.root.page` setting in the default.properties file.  This was set to `index.php` file, which didn't exist.

Once I changed this to footer.php file, it worked fine.